# Git shortcut for rebasing on origin

Tags: git

Is there a git shortcut that lets me rebase on the remote branch of the one I am working on at the moment?

E.g. if I work on `issue_101` it would do something like this:

```
   git fetch
   git rebase origin/issue_101
```

Obviously it should always take the fitting origin (`origin/issue_101` when I am working on `issue_101`; `issue_202` if I am working on `origin/issue_202` - not always the same. Apart from writing a batch script that searches my local .git folder for the matching remote branch and calls the corresponding commands, is there a faster/safer way?

Comment: `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: Perfect! More obvious than I thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-shot use :

```
git pull --rebase origin <branchName>
```

To automate it :

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
# then just do
git pull origin <branchName>
```

Comment: I just checked and after automating it, only typing `git pull` (w/o typing `origin <branchName>`) works as well. :)

Comment: @Florian Even shorter, yes, but depends on configuration. Glad it worked for your needs.